# Tokyo Ghouls Third Season

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Is there any news about tokyo ghouls third season in Anime? I have watched **Tokyo Ghoul: Jack**. It seems the episode of the history.  Did it has any connection with upcoming season?

Comment: the second season ended where there is a time skip in the manga. There is not enough material in the manga to make another season yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any official source, at the moment.

You should not believe any website that isn't credible. Like ChristianDAILYNews or KPopNews, they are nothing to do with anime. They reported on *Attack On Titan* airing in Summer of 2015 July 26th. That was very illogical for people to believe.

Trusted sources include AnimeNewsNetwork & CrunchyRoll. If no one like them are reporting official news, then do not believe someone. Make sure they are putting up their resources & credits, to where they are getting this "information."

*"Tokyo Ghoul's"* American Licensor Funimation. Their president said there would be a third season. However, he has no ties to the anime's production committee. It`s a strange thing for him to say, as a head of a large company.

That's it though.